# jQuery fast plotting libraries

Tags: jquery, web, plot

I got a webserver that will be called every 100 ms to retrieve a view values.
Those values need to be plotted in a monitor and connected by a line.

Its purely for fast demonstration purposes so no long-time solution
I was thinking about getting jQuery with some plotting library, but my concerns are if its fast enough and if it will look somewhat smooth?

Comment: I would suggest websockets http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091222/ if your browser can support it

Comment: [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flot seems quite nice for an easy plot of some data, works fast as well!

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/realtime.html